# How to check for geometry intersection (point in polygon) using OpenLayers3?

Tags: openlayers, turf

For example, I have [this vector](http://jsfiddle.net/abgcvqw3/40/) (It will be a more complicate linestring, not just a rectangle).

For a given coordinate (without clicks, just a latitude, longitude), how could I know (in an easy way, maybe collision?) if that coordinate is inside that vector?

[image]

---

**SOLUTION**

From the @JohnBarça answer, with turf library, this is working perfect:

```
var linestring1 = turf.linestring([
    [4.9020, 52.3667],
    [4.9030, 52.3667],
    [4.9040, 52.3667],
    [4.9050, 52.3667]
]);
var pt1 = turf.point([4.9040, 52.3667]);
var pt2 = turf.point([4.9060, 52.3667]);


var intersection = turf.intersect(pt1, linestring1);
if (intersection)
    alert('found pt1')
else
    alert('not found pt1')

intersection = turf.intersect(pt2, linestring1);
if (intersection)
    alert('found pt2')
else
    alert('not found pt2')
```

Comment: Which do you want OL2 or OL3? They are rather different.

Comment: @JohnBarça OL3 please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using turf.js is one approach I have seen, eg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654865/openlayers-3-area-intersection-between-geometries

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnBarça :) I'll investigate it and tell you something.

Comment: @JohnBarça It's work wonderful :) Could you reply an answer and I'll set as the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnBarça Do you know how to apply a width? xD It's not finding this var pt1 = turf.point([4.9040, 52.3669]);

Comment: I've done some Turf demos with OL3 (including `turf.insersect` operation at http://thomasg77.github.io/turf-ol3/ It may help for overall use of Turf

Comment: Hi @costales, I have added an answer. I'm not sure what you mean by adding a width in the comments, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OL3 does not support polygon intersection natively, but you can use the [turf.js library](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/), which seems to be rapidly growing in popularity and functionality.

Under the hood all geometries in turf.js are just GeoJSON, which, naturally, is supported natively in Javascript, making interop with OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc, very easy.

```
var pt = turf.point([0,0]);
var poly = turf.polygon([
   [[-1, -1],
    [-1, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [1, -1],
    [-1, -1]]
]);

var intersects = turf.intersect(poly, pt);
```

The [intersect function](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html) returns a feature representing the intersection or undefined if they do not intersect.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/310xdx54/) showing intersection and buffering.

Answer (score 4):

@JohnBarça  Just a note, while turf.intersect(polygon, point) does seem to work, it was pointed out to me that turf.inside(point, polygon) is the proper function to use, for checking that a point is inside a polygon. The turf.intersect() function is intended for polygons.

See variations, according to need:

- https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-inside
- https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-intersect
- https:// github.com/Turfjs/turf-within

Answer (score 3):

The logic here would be to first buffer the line upto the given width, and do a simple intersection query.

Both these operations require some topology and geometry operations, and can be done either in something like a Spatial Database e.g. PostGis, out even in an amazing JavaScript library called Turf.js

Comment: Thanks @Devdatta, I was thinking that OpenLayers could check a intersection by itself :(