# How to efficiently detect intersect between polygons?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, openlayers-2, intersection

So I'm trying to implement box selection in Leaflet.  Currently I'm using `turf`'s intersects function to detect if the box intersects with any of my GeoJSON polygon features.

However, this is very slow; with 180 polygons (about 500KB for GeoJSON data), it would take 3 seconds to iterate over every polygons.

I see that OpenLayers 3 has a box-selection feature which uses `ol.source.Vector.prototype.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` which in turns uses `ol.geom.flat.intersectsextent.linearRing` and so on.

The example that OpenLayers 3 gives has a GeoJSON source of 250KB, and it takes no time to iterate and highlight selected polygons.

Does anyone what algorithm OpenLayers uses? or is there any fast algorithm out there?

Comment: I suspect turf.js is the answer - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147904/79

Comment: That's what I'm using now, but it's still not as fast as I would expect.

Comment: Use the profiling features of your web browser's developer console. Which part of the code takes more time to run?

Comment: I got everything figured out. Its actually a different part which handles data pre processing that takes a long time